# How do I find all occurrences of a string in emacs?

Tags: search, emacs

There is a command that I can give Emacs to find all occurrences of a string in a file. This opens up a buffer so I can browse through them. I forgot what that command is. What is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`M-x occur`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html):

> Prompt for a regexp, and display a list showing each line in the buffer that contains a match for it. If you type `M-n` at the prompt, you can reuse search strings from previous incremental searches. The text that matched is highlighted using the `match` face. A numeric argument *n* specifies that *n* lines of context are to be displayed before and after each matching line.